# Changing the dot size in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Can one change the size of the dots in the table of contents, those that run between the section name and the page?

Eilon

Comment: Do you mean the radius of the dot or dot separation?

Comment: The `tocstyle` package should be able to do that: `\settocfeature{dothook}{…}` or `\settocstylefeature{leader}{…}` or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard classes, the dots between ToC entries and their page numbers are given by the kernel's `\@dottedtocline`; the dots are produced using `\leaders` to typeset copies of `\hbox{.}`; the separation between dots is controlled by `\@dotsep mu`, were `\@dotsep` is a number with default value of `4.5`. To change those settings, you can patch `\@dottedtocline` to replace `\hbox{.}` with whatever you want (a scaled dot, as in my example) and/or redefine `\@dotsep` to the desired value (I chose `12` in my example). The argument of `\mydot` controls the scaling factor of the default . used in the original definition (in my example I chose `2` for this factor)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% scale dots
\newcommand\mydot[1]{\scalebox{#1}{.}}
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}
  {\hbox{.}}
  {\hbox{\mydot{2}}}
  {}
  {}
% change separation between dots
\renewcommand\@dotsep{12} %default: 4.5
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}

\end{document}
```

The resulting document:

[image]

Of course, there's a number of packages that help you to achieve the same without having to know the originals definitions. For example, the same modifications can be achieved with a redefinition of `\cftdot` and `\cftdotsep` provided by the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand\mydot[1]{\scalebox{#1}{.}}
\renewcommand\cftdot{\mydot{2}}
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{12}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubection}

\end{document}
```

Another packages that could also be used to achieve the same redefinitions include:

- [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc).
- [`tocstyle`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle).