# How can I change the distance between the dots in the leader ToC memoir 3.7f ? (bug in \@dotsep)

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, memoir, bugs

I use `memoir 3.7f` and I can not change `\@dotsep`.

The bug was tested in two PCs.

How can I change the disctance between the dots now?

`memoir` documentation citations:

p.142 `The distance, in math units2 between the dots in the leader is given by the value of \@dotsep.`

p.142 `The standard values for these internal commands are:...\@dotsep=4.5. The values can be changed by using \renewcommand, in spite of the fact that the first twoappear to be lengths.`

p.143 See, please `\@dotsep` depicted in Fig. 9.2.

p.145 `The dots in the leaders can be eliminated by increasing \@dotsep to a large value: \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}`

etc.

One of the succesfull cases of using `\@dotsep` mentioned in answers on the following question:

[Changing the dot size in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159998/changing-the-dot-size-in-the-table-of-contents)

MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir} % tested version 3.7f
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{1}
\makeatother
%\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
%    %% delete boxes
%    \renewcommand\numberlinebox[2]{#2} % for sections
%    \renewcommand\chapternumberlinebox[2]{#2} % for chapters 
%    %% set dot and space
%    \renewcommand\cftchapteraftersnum{.\space} 
%    \renewcommand\cftsectionaftersnum{.\space}        
%    \renewcommand\cftsubsectionaftersnum{.\space}    
%    \renewcommand\cftsubsubsectionaftersnum{.\space}  
%    %%enumeration levels in the ToC and text
%    \settocdepth{subsection} 
%    \setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
%    \setrmarg{2.55em plus1fil} %hyphenation is forbidden
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection{First subsection  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\setcounter{chapter}{11}
\chapter{Another chapter long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\section{First section  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection{First subsection  long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\subsection*{Short conclusion with long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{susubsection}{Short conclusion}
\end{document}
```

PDF

[image]

Comment: @daleif, is it a bug or new feature?

Comment: Why do you think `\cftdotsep` uses `\@dotsep`? Change `\cftdotsep` (you can always do as I do, look in the code), I'll check what the manual says.

Comment: Remember the first part of that chapter describes how this is done in the standard classes, the `memoir` setup is then explained laters in the manual. Changing `\cftdotsep` works fine.

Comment: @daleif, and what about renewcommand of \@dotsep? \cftdotsep works perfect. You can try 10000 instead of 1.

Comment: ??? `memoir` does not use `\@dotsep` in its TOC macros, it uses `\cftdotsep`

Comment: @daleif, perhaps, it used to be in `memoir`. I've already updated the question with page numbers and citations about `\@dotsep` from the`memoir` documentation. How can I change the distance between dots now?

Comment: @daleif, I've successfuly checked `\cftdotsep`! Many thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned the part of the manual you are looking at describes the general latex toc methods. After that it is explained how memoir makes an interface for this. Thus doing this in a different way. Btw you should not self answer your question when someone else fave the answer is the comments, more polite to ask them to provide an answer you can then accept.

Comment: @daleif, I thought you are too busy to post the answer. Now there is no one! You are wellcome to provide the full answer. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many parts of the `memoir` manual, a chapter starts by explaining how a certain feature is done in standard latex (ie the standard classes). This is to give the reader a basic idea of how this feature does its thing and thus better understand what the memoir implementation of this feature does and how the configuration macros for the feature is related.

So, in standard latex, the space between does in the toc is controlled by `\@dotsep`, a protected macro (the @). In memoir, the interface uses \cftdotsep instead, a normal macro the user can easily change.

Thus to change the dot sep, use

```
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{6.5}
```

Or similar